# InfoPath form writing to multiple SharePoint lists

Tags: forms, list, ms-access, sharepoint, infopath

I've been looking for a way of having my InfoPath form write to multiple SharePoint lists. I wanted something similar to how MS Access forms work since I wish to move my MS Access programs over to SharePoint.

Is it even possible to replicate the queries and procedures from MS Access/SQL Database over to SharePoint?

Comment: You can try to add submit rule to submit event http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/automatically-submit-a-form-by-using-a-rule-HP001100272.aspx.